# QtQuickCompiler was not found with CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, compilation, qtquick2, qt6

I tried to use the QtQuickCompiler the first time, so I looked in the Qt docs. (https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html). But if I call `find_package(Qt6QuickCompiler)` it shows me,

```
By not providing "FindQt6QuickCompiler.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt6QuickCompiler", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6QuickCompiler"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt6QuickCompilerConfig.cmake
    qt6quickcompiler-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt6QuickCompiler" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "Qt6QuickCompiler_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "Qt6QuickCompiler" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

After this I searched the Qt directory, but I did not find it. Is there no QtQuickCompiler as of Qt6? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sry, the usage of Qt5QuickCompiler was a test^^. I copied the wrong log. I have updated it.

Comment: I found in my Qt-directory a Qt6QuickCompilerConfig.cmake.in - file. It contains the message: WARNING "Use qt6_add_resources instead of qtquick_compiler_add_resources.""QML and JavaScript files are automatically compiled then.". So i don't need the compiler anymore?

Comment: What seems to me is that by default the QtQuickCompiler functionality is already used